# Distribute array values so maximum will be 1 and minimum will be 0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I think this must be a basic math operation but I really can't figure it out. I need to get an array of values between 0 and 1 based on values from a given array. So, for example, if we have an initial array `[24, 128, 52]` the resulting array should be `[0, 1, 0.5]`. Maximum and minimum values should be always be 1 and 0 respectively and the rest should be proportionately in between them.

How can I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with an array:

```
let sourceArray = [24.0, 128.0, 52.0]
```

Store the minimum and maximum elements:

```
let min = minElement(sourceArray) // 24.0
let max = maxElement(sourceArray) // 128.0
```

Normalize each element and map the results to a new array:

```
let results = sourceArray.map { ($0 - min) / (max - min) }
```

`results` is:

```
[0, 1, 0.2692307692307692]
```

You specified you wanted `[0, 1, 0.5]`, but I think that's wrong, since you said "the rest should be proportionately in between them". Inputting `[24.0, 128.0, 76.0]` would output `[0, 1, 0.5]`.

**Note:** the source array can't be `[Int]` or the map operation will round the result to either 1 or 0. If you need to work with `[Int]` you'll have to convert each element in the `map` operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a note for future readers. If you're using Swift 2.0 you'll need to use sourceArray.minElement() instead minElement(sourceArray)

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 5 use:

```
let min = sourceArray.min()
let max = sourceArray.max()
// will produce optionals! Unwrap them if you are sure they won't be nil
let results = sourceArray.map { ($0 - min!) / (max! - min!) }
```

Comment: This will crash if min and max have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let array: [Double] = [24, 128, 52]
array.map { [range = ClosedRange(encompassing: array)!] in
  range.normalize($0)!
}
```

```swift
public extension ClosedRange {
  /// A range whose bounds are the extremes of a given sequence.
  ///
  /// - Returns: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  init?<Bounds: Sequence>(encompassing bounds: Bounds)
  where Bounds.Element == Bound {
    guard let initialRange = ( bounds.first.map { $0...$0 } )
    else { return nil }

    self = bounds.dropFirst().reduce(into: initialRange) { range, bound in
      if bound < range.lowerBound {
        range = bound...range.upperBound
      } else if bound > range.upperBound {
        range = range.lowerBound...bound
      }
    }
  }
}

public extension ClosedRange where Bound: AdditiveArithmetic {
  /// `upperBound - lowerBound`
  var magnitude: Bound { upperBound - lowerBound }
}

public extension ClosedRange where Bound: FloatingPoint {
  /// A value whose unit is the `magnitude` of this range,
  /// and whose origin is `lowerBound`.
  ///
  /// - Note: Not clamped between 0 and 1.
  ///
  /// - Returns: `nil` when the range has zero magnitude.
  func normalize(_ bound: Bound) -> Bound? {
    try? (bound - lowerBound) ÷ magnitude
  }
```

```swift
infix operator ÷: MultiplicationPrecedence

public extension FloatingPoint {
  /// - Throws: `DivisionByZeroError<Self>`
  static func ÷ (numerator: Self, denominator: Self) throws -> Self {
    guard denominator != 0
    else { throw DivisionByZeroError(numerator: numerator) }

    return numerator / denominator
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The first element of the sequence.
  /// - Note: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  var first: Element? {
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    return iterator.next()
  }
}
```

```swift
// Division isn't actually found in `Numeric`,
// but it does seem to be found in all the important protocols that inherit from it.
public struct DivisionByZeroError<Numerator: Swift.Numeric>: Error {
  public let numerator: Numerator

  public init(numerator: Numerator) {
    self.numerator = numerator
  }
}
```